# Trouble testing redux async action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am having trouble testing the following asynchronous Redux action.

```
export default function getBestPracticesInfo() {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        axios.get("testurl")
            .then(response => {
                return dispatch({type: "GET_BEST_PRACTICE", payload: response.data})
            }).catch(error => {
            return error
        })
    }
}
```

I'd like to simply verify that the action dispatches the correct action with the expected payload. To do this I am mocking out the `axios` call, the `dispatch` and `getState()` methods. The mocked `dispatch()` method returns a promise with the data used to call it. That way I can make sure my test assertion doesn't fire before my `axios` promise has resolved. However, what is happening is that `action(dispatch, getState)` in my test is returning undefined and I am stumped as to why. I am expecting it to return a promise.

```
describe('metaDataActions tests', () => {
    let mock;
    beforeEach(() => {
        mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
        mock.onGet('testurl').reply(200, {data: 'TEST BEST PRACTICE RESPONSE'});
        sessionStorage.clear();
    });

    it('should call getBestPracticesInfo', () => {
        const getState = ()=> {return {metaData: {meta: {api: {bestPractices: '/api/v1/best_practices'}}}}};
        const dispatch = jest.fn(info => {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                resolve(info);
            })
        });
        const action = getBestPracticesInfo();
        action(dispatch, getState).then(res =>
            expect(res).toEqual({type: "GET_BEST_PRACTICES_INFO", payload: response.data})
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the action code a return statement is necessary to return the result of the axios promise.

```
export default function getBestPracticesInfo() {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        return axios.get("testurl")
            .then(response => {
                return dispatch({type: "GET_BEST_PRACTICE", payload: response.data})
            }).catch(error => {
            return error
        })
    }
}
```